# running HAXM for android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualization, intel, bios

Every time I try to run it I get an error saying "This computer meets the requirements for HAXM, but Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) is not turned on. HAXM cannot be installed until VT-x is enabled." I need help solving this issue. I have already enabled Virtualization in my computers BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Cpu has to support ND/XD (execute disable) bit & Virtualization (check ark.intel.com)

 - Dowwnload the separate installer rather than install thru Android studio
at https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager
 
- Set vt in BIOS.
 
- Turn off Hypervisor and ND bit on with these 2 commands:

     bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

           bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn

-   Turn off antivirus  - especially Avast (Avast:  disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting)

Then either restart the PC or do a sc stop/start intelhaxm

Answer (score 0):

Below two steps worked for me .

Initially i took time to figure out the vt-x on HP windows7 BIOS, but after some research i could figure out that is in security->System Security->Enable vt-x.

But then i got NX bit problem i.e. it is not enabled, then i ran "bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn" from command prompt, and everything worked fine.